# Averaging individual predictions in a group

Tags: linear-model, forecast-combination, mean

I created linear model to give prediction for a team member (individual). Can I use this model to give average (individual) prediction in a team by providing average values of features among team members, or by averaging predictions by each team member?

---

*Example:*

**Training Data**

Independent Variables are Task Count and Average Points while Points are y-value.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\text{Team Id} & \text{Sprint Id} & \text{Team Member} & \text{Task Count} & \text{Avg Points} & \text{Points} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 123 & Mike & 4 & 5 & 20 \\ \hline
\text{2} & 273 & Chris & 5 & 3 & 15 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 403 & James & 7 & 2 & 14 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 298 & Paul & 2 & 6 & 12 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

**Actual Data that linear model will use to predict**

I average independent values by category within a team. The averaged values for each category will be given to predict *average story points for an individual* within a team.
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
\text{Team Id} & \text{Sprint Id} & \text{Avg. Task Count} & \text{Avg. Avg Points} & \text{Avg. Points} \\ \hline
\text{1} & 342 & 4 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\text{2} & 713 & 5 & 5 & 3 \\ \hline
\text{3} & 663 & 6 & 7 & 2 \\ \hline
\text{4} & 188 & 7 & 2 & 6 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Not sure if I can use the model with average values by category to predict average points.

Comment: Post an example in your question.

Comment: @user2974951 I just added the example in my question above.

Comment: This *can* be done, but one is inclined to suspect responses within groups may be strongly correlated, so you should be reluctant to assume independence of responses: consider using a model that accommodates within-group dependence.

Comment: @whuber - Is there such model to accomodate within-group dependence? Im using OLS regression at the moment. Otherwise, I should find other features which align with indepence of responses.

Comment: There are many.  Two common ones are mixed models (in which variation of individuals within the group is modeled with a single Normally-distributed random variable) and generalized least squares models (in which some explicit form of correlation among within-group individuals is hypothesized).  BTW, in at least one case you seem to use the word "dependent" in your question where you mean *independent.*  Also, the connection between the two tables in the question is truly obscure--they aren't clarifying what you're trying to do.

Comment: @whuber - Thanks for your response. Yes, you are right. I corrected my question to use the term 'independent'. I just want to know if I can use the model (which is trained with non-averaged feature values) with averaged data to predict average y-values.

Comment: Your training data seems to have a *nonlinear* relationship: points = task_count x avg.points ?

Comment: That's not much of a question--yes, you can use the model (as you could use any model) in that way, because the rules of mathematics permit it.  The questions I think you want to ask are (1) how to estimate the uncertainty of that prediction and (2) what models can give reliable predictions with least uncertainty.

Comment: @whuber - Yes, I was checking feasibility of using the model in that way before properly starting feature (highly correlated) and model selection. I am planning the project :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are asking is:

- Given a linear model (e.g. `y=a1*x1 + a2*x2+...+b`),
- applied to a group of data points, (e.g. each data point is a player, with their own features (e.g. `x1_i, x2_i,...` for each player `i`),
- would averaging the features across players (e.g. using `x1_avg, ...`), and using them in the model, give the same result as using the features of each player and averaging the results?

If so, the answer is - **yes, but only for a linear model** (i.e. not a quadratic, polynomial, neural network or whatever).

This can be verified quite simply: for example, if there are only two players and two features: [image]

Comment: This partially correct.  The issue isn't whether averaging is appropriate for *estimating* the mean response: even in a nonlinear model, one would estimate the mean response of some arbitrary set of individuals by averaging the individual estimates.  The hard part is constructing a *prediction interval* for that response, especially for groups of individuals who are somehow related and not just randomly selected.

Comment: Thanks. I am asking in general to see if I can use linear model (which is trained with non-average data) with average data.